# Question about Peano form of the remainder

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined on a closed interval [a, b], differentiable on the open interval (a, b) $n-1$ times.

$x_0$ belongs to [a, b]. Suppose that we have:$$f(x_0)=0,f'(x_0)=0,f''(x_0)=0,...,f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$$
Also suppose that the function admits the nth derivative at $x_0$. In this case my book says that is:$$f(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}[f^{(n)}(x_0)+\sigma(x)]$$
where:$$\begin{matrix} \lim_{x \to x_0}\sigma(x)=0 \end{matrix}$$
It seems that in my book's proof must be (because it isn't completely clear ):
$$\begin{matrix} \lim_{x \to x_0}f^{(n)}(x)\end{matrix}=f^{(n)}(x_0)$$
It means that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$...but in the theorem it isn't mentioned that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$; I know that the first $(n-1)$th derivatives are continuous in $x_0$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ exists. So is the continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at $x=x_0$ necessary to prove the theorem?

Comment: no, but if you assume more, such as continuity, you can get more precise forms for the remainder. It would help for you to explain why you think your book's proof requires continuity of the last derivative.

Comment: Can you give the title of the book ?

Answer (score -2):

Proof's book:

If $x\ne x_0 $ and $n>1$, according to Cauchy's mean value theorem, we have:$$\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}=\frac{f^{(n-1)}(\eta)}{\phi^{(n-1)}(\eta)}$$

where $\eta$ is a suitable interior point of the interval $[x_0,x]$ and $\phi(x)=(x-x_0)^n$.
Since:$$\phi^{(n-1)}(\eta)=n!(\eta-x_0)$$$$f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$$the last formula I wrote becomes:$$\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{f^{(n-1)}(\eta)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{\eta-x_0}$$
Now:
$$\begin{matrix} \lim_{x \to x_0}(n!\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}) \end{matrix}=\begin{matrix} \lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(\eta)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{\eta-x_0} \end{matrix}=f^{(n)}(x_0)$$I'm stuck here: in the second limit; I think that writing means that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$. Am I right?
Let's keep on with the proof; let:$$\sigma(x)=n!\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}-f^{(n)}(x_0)$$ for $x\ne x_0 $ and $\sigma(x_0)=0$ we have:
$$\begin{matrix} \lim_{x \to x_0}\sigma(x) \end{matrix}=0$$
Finally:$$f(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}[f^{(n)}(x_0)+\sigma(x)]$$QED

My doubt is: is the continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at $x=x_0$ necessary to prove the theorem? If it isn't can someone explain me why the second limit is valid?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No... The second limit is just the definition of the derivative.